# Explodir coluna em diversas colunas usando lista como base para posicionar elementos

Tags: python, pandas

Tendo o dataframe abaixo como exemplo, desejo pegar a coluna "`B`" e explodí-la em diversas colunas usando uma lista de elementos para posicionar cada valor na sua respectiva coluna destino.

### Dataframe de teste

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], 
                   "B": [["a","b","c"],["a","c"],["b"]], 
                   "C": ["agua", "banana", "casa"]})

print(df)

   A          B       C
0  1  [a, b, c]    agua
1  2     [a, c]  banana
2  3        [b]    casa
```

### Explodindo coluna

```
exploded = pd.DataFrame(df["B"].tolist(), index=df.index)

print(exploded)

   0     1     2
0  a     b     c
1  a     c  None
2  b  None  None
```

Achei que inserir nomes de colunas no comando anterior pudesse ajudar,

```
exploded = pd.DataFrame(df["B"].tolist(), index=df.index, columns=["col_a", "col_b", "col_c"])

print(exploded)

  col_a col_b col_c
0     a     b     c
1     a     c  None
2     b  None  None
```

A ideia é fazer o merge desta saída com o dataframe original.

Todavia, a saída desejada é:

### Saída desejada

```
  col_a col_b col_c
0     a     b     c
1     a  None     c
2  None     b  None
```

Para posicionar os elementos na coluna correta, gostaria de usar uma lista de elementos já ordenados. Segundo o exemplo acima, a lista seria: `["a", "b", "c"]`. Porém, aceito outras sugestões.

**Nota**: Pode ser `None` ou `NaN`

Comment: Eu parti duma transformação `pd.DataFrame(df["B"].transform(lambda e: ["a" in e, "b" in e, "c" in e]).tolist())` o que é basicamente um for loop, não sei se é adequado aos seus requisitos?

Comment: @AugustoVasques, pensei em algo parecido usando o apply. Sei que vou perder performance, mas acho que vai atender ao que preciso. Pois, este foi um exemplo com "a, b, c", tenho várias colunas com quantidade de itens e categorias diferentes. De qualquer forma, vou dar uma olhada no `transform` para ver se ele atende melhor que o apply. Obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 1):

Baseado no comentário do [@Augusto Vasques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/137387/augusto-vasques), cheguei à seguinte solução:

```
import numpy as np

def coloca_no_lugar(row, gabarito):
    if not isinstance(row, list):
        return [np.nan] * len(gabarito)
    return [item if item in row else np.nan for item in gabarito]
```

**Nota** O teste de instância se dá para garantir que o Python não irá gerar uma *Exception* no caso de encontrar um item não iterável no valor passado (row).

Tendo esta função acima, basta chamar usando `apply` ou `transform`

```
pd.DataFrame(df["B"].transform(coloca_no_lugar, gabarito=["a", "b", "c"]).tolist(), columns=["col_a","col_b","col_c"])
```

A saída do comando acima é:

```
  col_a col_b col_c
0     a     b     c
1     a  None     c
2  None     b  None
```

Com isto, basta:

1. Fazer o merge baseado no `index`
2. Fazer o drop da coluna "B"

**Nota** nenhum dos dois itens acima faz parte da pergunta original.

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra forma de chegar na saída esperada é usando os comandos `.explode()` passando a coluna **B** e `pivot()` usando como parâmetros a coluna **B** também em `columns` e `values`, desta forma:

```
df2 = df.explode('B')
df2 = df2.pivot( columns='B', values ='B')
df2.head()
#saída:

B   a   b   c
0   a   b   c
1   a   NaN c
2   NaN b   NaN
```

Para renomear as colunas é possível passar um array direto para o `.columns`, ou algo mais dinâmico com list comprehension.

```
df2.columns = ['col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c']
#ou 
df2.columns = ['col_' + column for column in df2.columns]
df2.head()
    col_a   col_b   col_c
0   a       b       c
1   a       NaN     c
2   NaN     b       NaN
```